# How to generate a Self Signed OpenSSL certificate with Ansible playbooks? private key file does not exist

Tags: ansible

I am showing my task schema

```
---
- name: Ensure directory exists for local self-signed TLS certs.
  file:
    path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}"
    state: directory

- name: Generate an OpenSSL private key.
  community.crypto.x509_certificate:
    path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}/privkey.pem"
    privatekey_path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}/privkey.pem"
    provider: selfsigned
```

When I run playbook I got

```
TASK [Ensure directory exists for local self-signed TLS certs.] ****************
changed: [default]

TASK [Generate an OpenSSL private key.] ****************************************
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The private key file /etc/ssl/private/https.an/privkey.pem does not exist"}
```

I looked at official examples([ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_module.html#examples))

```
- name: Generate a Self Signed OpenSSL certificate
  community.crypto.x509_certificate:
    path: /etc/ssl/crt/ansible.com.crt
    privatekey_path: /etc/ssl/private/ansible.com.pem
    csr_path: /etc/ssl/csr/ansible.com.csr
    provider: selfsigned
```

If I go `vagrant ssh` and check

```
root@https:/etc/ssl# ll
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Feb 12  2022 ./
drwxr-xr-x 83 root root  4096 Mar  6 12:00 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 16384 Feb 12  2022 certs/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10909 Apr 20  2020 openssl.cnf
drwx------  3 root root  4096 Mar  6 12:00 private/
```

And

```
root@https:/etc/ssl/private# ll
total 12
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Mar  6 12:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 12  2022 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 12:00 https.an/
```

server name is https.an.
That folder is empty.
Should I generate keys on my own?
How it comes that Anisble can not automate this,or somethins is worng with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate the key by yourself, ansible can handle it like this:
Doc: [Openssl Key module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/openssl_privatekey_module.html)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - server_hostname: localhost
    - key_size: 2048
    - passphrase: passphrase
    - key_type: DSA
  tasks:
    - name: Generate an OpenSSL private key
      openssl_privatekey:
        path: "{{ certificate_dir }}/{{ server_hostname }}/privkey.pem"
        size: "{{ key_size }}"
        type: "{{ key_type }}"
        backup: yes
```

After doing it you reference the key in the community.crypto.x509_certificate module.